# Pages keeps deleting empty lines when I change the font style

Tags: macos, pages, font

I am running the latest version of Pages (5.6). The problem occurs whenever I position the caret on a new, empty line.

If I change the font style to bold (or turn off bold), Pages automatically highlights (selects) the empty line, which reveals an invisible format character. If there is text below the line the caret is positioned on, after I start typing, Pages deletes the entire line and moves the text up because the line was empty to begin with.

Screenshot to better illustrate this. The caret is positioned between the two lines of text. When I, for instance, turn bold on or off, the following happens:

[image: Screenshot]

The new line is selected, so once I start typing, Pages deletes the entire line and the new format style is cleared. This is really irritating because every time I change the font style now, I have to deselect the new line manually by clicking away from it, using the arrow keys, or something like that so it won't overwrite the new line.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: I see what you mean.  Only way I found around this is to left arrow before typing.

Comment: Facing this exact issue right now. It's been frustrating me to no end.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed an annoyance with **Pages**.

One way around this:

- While at the end of the preceding line and *before* adding the new line, change your formatting, then tap return and type your new line.